# PowerBI - Limiting the Slicer/Filter dropdown option values of "Product_Name" column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Need help on PowerBI - Limiting the Slicer/Filter drop-down option values of "Product_Name"

- Background:

For a Power BI requirement, I have a "Fact Table" where two categories of data reside "Distributor" and "Retailer" . Distributor/Retailer are defined by a Ownership_ID, a particular PBi report needs both categories of information.

- RLS is applied to the "Fact Table", once I select Distributor via Slicer, Retailer information is ruled out, only when Distributor and Retailer are the same (Distributor is also a retailer) I get both details.
- Segregated Information

  - Using only "Fact_Table" - for distributor
  - Brought a copy of "Fact_Table" calling it "Fact_New" for Retlaier information, it is disconnected from other tables (except the calendar dimension table)
- Using a bridge table "Product_Names" to connect "Fact_Table" (Distributor) to "Fact_New" (Retailer) via "product_name" field, At report using the Bridge table "Product_name" as a slicer but all product names are visible.

e.g. ABC distributor has 10 products in their catalog, bridge table "Product Name" has all 50 products names visible (out of which 40 are blank for ABC distributor)

- Query:
  how can I limit the values of the "Product Name" drop-down to not show the blank values for all distributors.